# Navigation bar wont hide after closing keyboard

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

When I fill in a input field and close the keyboard my navigation bar wont hide.

Before I fill in the input field its hidden.

I tried multiple solutions but none of them work for me.

```
this.Window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen); // hide the status bar

int uiOptions = (int)Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility;

uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.LowProfile;
uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen;
uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation;
uiOptions |= (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky;

Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
```

This is the code i have in my `OnCreate` method in my `MainActivity`.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How  can i hide  the navigation bar again after the keyboard is closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/xiaolvzi/NavigationBarTest) is the demo.

Implement `View.IOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener` interface:

```
    public void OnSystemUiVisibilityChange([GeneratedEnum] StatusBarVisibility visibility)
    {
        if (((int)visibility & (int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen) == 0)
        {
            Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)uiOptions;
        }

    }
```

Add the listener for your DecorView:

```
Window.DecorView.SetOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(this);
```

Override `OnWindowFocusChanged`:

```
    public override void OnWindowFocusChanged(bool hasFocus)
    {
        base.OnWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = (StatusBarVisibility)((int)SystemUiFlags.Fullscreen
            | (int)SystemUiFlags.ImmersiveSticky
            | (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutHideNavigation
            | (int)SystemUiFlags.LayoutStable
            | (int)SystemUiFlags.HideNavigation);
    }
```